# Edit Commands List in Telegram with Telepot

Tags: python, command, telegram

I'm trying to create bot for telegram and I want to have custom /Commands list in each state. how can I do that? I'm using telepot library for write bot in python.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `/setcommands@BotFather`, it can't set different list to each users.

But you can try [reply keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup) or [inline keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup), see this [demo](https://core.telegram.org/bots#inline-keyboards-and-on-the-fly-updating).